# Does lengthening prison sentences reduce crime rates?

Tags: criminology

I have heard time and again that increasing the length of prison sentences produces little or no improvements in crime rates. It is said that increasing the probability of arrest after a crime has much better results.

Is there evidence for this (especially in developing countries)?

Comment: I had trouble finding an example claim which didn't also provide evidence to support it.

Comment: Reduce crime rates inside or outside prison?

Comment: rates outside prison.

Comment: If someone is in prison, that person cannot commit a crime. Seems like it would have to help, unless it is like musical chairs (one criminal is caught, someone else steps in to their place).